# How to convert 2D matrix to 3D by embeddings in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 2D matrix with shape `[batch_size, seq_len]` where values of the 1st dimension are from range [0, num_classes - 1].

I also have another embedding matrix with shape `[num_classes, embedding_size]`.

How can I transform 2D matrix to 3D with shape `[batch_size, seq_len, embedding_size]` by replacing the class labels (scalar) in 2D matrix with its embedding vector?

I know how to implement it in for-loop way, but how it can be vectorized?

Comment: torch.nn.functional.embedding

Comment: @bobcat Is there any numpy like method, without gradients?

Comment: `with torch.no_grad(): your_code()`

Comment: ... actually, if your input doesn't `requires_grad`, then that should be enough

Comment: @bobcat thank it is good suggestion. and I update this question to be a numpy question.